# Understanding a Probability Table

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have two sample spaces

$$
\Omega_{\phi} = \{\phi, \neg \phi \}
$$

$$
\Omega_{x} = \{x, \neg x \}
$$

with probability distributions $P_{\phi} : \mathcal{P}(\Omega_{\phi}) \rightarrow [0,1]$ and $P_{x} : \mathcal{P}(\Omega_{x}) \rightarrow [0,1]$ respectively.  In the table below, I filled in arbitrary values for $P_x$ and $P_\phi$.

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
 & \phi & \neg \phi & \\
\hline
x &? &? &0.5 \\
\hline
\neg x &? &? &0.5 \\
\hline
&0.75 &0.25 &1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

From the table, we can see that $P_\phi(\phi) = 0.75$ and $P_\phi(\neg \phi) = 0.25$. Likewise, we can see that $P_x(x) = 0.5$ and $P_x(\neg x) = 0.5$.

**Question 1:** Now I'm trying to understand the meaning of the portions of the table tagged "?". I'm assuming these squares represent the value of the **new** probability distribution defined on $\Omega_\phi \times \Omega_x$. This would mean that the value of the top left question mark is equal to $P(\phi, x)$. Is this the correct notation and viewpoint?

**Question 2:** Are the value of the "?" squares now already pre-determined in the sense that the value of the marginal probabilities (arbitrarily defined above) **force** them to take on certain values already? Put differently, is there more than one solution for the table above?